# How to estimate 95% confidence interval for the mean of proportions in a very small sample (n=3)

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-error, percentage

I have a dataset composed of 6 independent observations, where values are percentages (proportions) of a specific element in a set. There are 2 groups of observations, and each has $n=3$ observations.

Is there a procedure that is able to deal with this very low sample size and provide confidence intervals for the average proportions of each group?

Comment: what's wrong with the usual procedure?

Comment: @rep_ho Thanks for the comment. I should probably have written my question differently. Does the formula $mean +/- z * sigma/sqrt(n)$ suffice?

Comment: Yes, provided $z$ is computed with a Student $t$ distribution with $2$ d.f.  That's the "usual procedure" to which @rep referred.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, all clear!

Comment: Hang on, the random variables aren't normally distributed ("values are defined between 0 and 1").  What distribution are you assuming?

Comment: @Creosote Given the robustness of the Student $t$ test, it's still a good procedure unless more can be said about how the data are distributed in these intervals.

Comment: @Creosote the variables are percentages, but I'm unsure of what else can be assumed about their distribution.

Comment: @whuber don't you need higher sample size for CLT to kick in? or this is not an issue if you use t.distribution?

Comment: @whuber and Creosote I think there is a mistake on my side here - the values are percentages computed for each observation. For this reason, the mean and standard error should be computed differently. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Is this any help? -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Hi @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica thanks! I ended up using this actually. With the implementation in https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint.html#statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint